# c# - доступ к массиву одного класса из другого

Tags: c#, массивы

Задача: сделать методы, для выдачи зарплаты одному и всем работникам в классе accountant

Есть код:

```
сlass Employee
{
    int salary;
    int money;
    string position;

    public Employee(int salary, int money, string position)
    {
        this.salary = salary;
        this.money = money;
        this.position = position;
    }
    public void TakeSalary()
    {
        money = money + salary;
    }
}

class Accountant : Employee
{
    public Accountant(int salary, int money) : base(salary, money, "Accountant")
    {

    }

    public void GiveSalary(Employee obj)
    {
        obj.TakeSalary();
    }
    public void GiveSalaryForAll()
    {
        foreach (Employee obj in Boss.GetEmployeeList())
        {
            obj.TakeSalary();
        }
    }

class Boss : Employee
{
    List<Employee> employeeList;

    public Boss(int salary, int money, List<Employee> employeeList) : base (salary, money, "Boss")
    {
        this.employeeList = new List<Employee>();
    }

    public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList()
    {
        return this.employeeList;
    }
```

VS ругается:

```
Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Boss.GetEmployeeList()" требуется ссылка на объект. [Company]
```

P.S: public не предлагать.

P.P.S: есть ли альтернатива

```
Employee.TakeSalary();
```

чтобы у работника не было доступа к такому методу?

Comment: `Boss.GetEmployeeList()` - это вызов статического метода, которого у вас нет

Answer (score 0):

не совсем понял какая у вас задача, но все возможно эта реализация вам подойдет если нужно выдавать зарплату то это должно помочь

```
   class Employees
    {

        List<Employee> employees;    


        void Add(int solary, int money, string position)
        {
            employees.Add(new Employee(solary, money, position));
        }

        void TakeSalaryAll()
        {

            foreach (Employee element in employees)
            {
                element.TakeSalary();
            }
        }

        void TakeSalaryIndex(int index)
        {
            if(index > 0 && index <= employees.Count())
            {
                employees[index].TakeSalary();
            }
        }       


    }
```